# Relative lyaout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I am making an android app for diabetic patients. In that app I want to show the food item with their quantity for every meal for diet control. It should look somewhat like below:

```
RICE          100gm
POTATO        50gm
FISH          60gm
```

Those info will be obtained from my database dynamically. However I am facing problem arranging them. I want the food items to be aligned left and quantity aligned right of the screen. As below (dots denote the screen )

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|RICE                                             100gm |
|POTATO                                            50gm |
|FISH                                              60gm |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

To do that I have declared a relative Layout in xml file. The code looks as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

All I need to do now is to create textview and add them to this relative layout dynamically. But I am confused how to do that. Any hint please...

The final output should look something like below :

[image: it should look something like below]

Comment: A had a go at setting a more fitting title for your question but feel free to make it more appropriate if my selection does not apply

Comment: It will be easier for you to use a `ListView`.

Comment: Thanx. but may be listview cannot give me what I want... @Szymon

Comment: Try adding a `RelativeLayout` for each item. In the layout set up one 'TextView' to be `alignParentLeft`, one `alignParentRight`. Then 2 other `TextView` below the corresponding ones above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with @Szymon that the best way to do this is with a ListView. However, if you don't want to do that, here's how I would do it:

1. Create a separate layout for each item you want to display. Make it a RelativeLayout, and place all the TextViews there in accordance to how you want the items to be displayed (alignParentRight / alignParentLeft).
2. Dynamically create views by inflating this new layout, assign the text of the TextViews by using findViewById() on the views you inflate during runtime
3. Add the views to the LinearLayout

(EDIT: How to do Step 2:)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, null);
TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv1.setText(myText);
```

Comment: Please Can you explain your step no 2 in short.. @Gil Moshayof